# Change font-weight to bold on checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Doing some custom css on these `input` and `label` elements to style a checkbox. I'm trying to `bold` the `font-weight` when user clicks on the checkbox, and then toggle `regular` if they click again to toggle the box. Stumped on this, pun intended.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tn7cyvt/7/)

```js
$(function() {
  var action = 1;
  $('.control--checkbox input').on("click", goBold);

  function goBold() {
    if (action == 1) {
      fontWeight("bold");
      action = 2;
    } else {
      fontWeight("400");
      action = 1;
    }
  }

  function fontWeight(val) {
    $('.control--checkbox').css({
      fontWeight: val
    })
  }
});
```

```css
.control-group {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.control-group .control {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.control-group .control input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.control-group .control__indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: white;
}

.control-group .control--radio .control__indicator {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.control-group .control:hover input~.control__indicator,
.control-group .control input:focus~.control__indicator {
  background: #fff;
}

.control-group .control input:checked~.control__indicator {
  background: #fff;
}

.control-group .control__indicator:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.control-group .control input:checked~.control__indicator:after {
  display: block;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.control-group .control--radio .control__indicator:after {
  left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox .control__indicator:after {
  left: 6px;
  top: 0;
  width: 7px;
  height: 14px;
  border: solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.control-group .control--checkbox input:checked~.control__indicator {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox input:disabled~.control__indicator:after {
  border-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox input:disabled~.control__indicator:after {
  border-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox .control__indicator {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="facet-group">
  <h3>Operating System</h3>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control control--checkbox">Apple iOS (42)
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
    <label class="control control--checkbox">Android (20)
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
    <label class="control control--checkbox">Windows (8)
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function() {

   $('.control--checkbox input').on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).data('isbold')) {
      $(this).parent().css('font-weight', 'normal') 
      $(this).data('isbold', false)
    } else {
      $(this).parent().css('font-weight', 'bold')
      $(this).data('isbold', true)
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Although the pure css methods may be preferred, this certainly did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `action` checks are unnecessary. You can check if they are checked using `event.target.checked` which will return `true` or `false` values.

```js
$(function () {

  

  $('.control--checkbox input').on("change", goBold);

  function goBold(event) {
      if(event.target.checked) {
        fontWeight($(this), "bold");
      } else {
        fontWeight($(this), "400");
      }
  }

  function fontWeight(element, val) {
    element.parent().css({fontWeight: val})
  }
});
```

```css
.control-group {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.control-group .control {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 18px;
 padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.control-group .control input {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 opacity: 0;
}

.control-group .control__indicator {
 position: absolute;
 top: 2px;
 left: 0;
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 background: white;
}

.control-group .control--radio .control__indicator {
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.control-group .control:hover input ~ .control__indicator,
  .control-group .control input:focus ~ .control__indicator {
 background: #fff;
}

.control-group .control input:checked ~ .control__indicator {
 background: #fff;
}

.control-group .control__indicator:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
}

.control-group .control input:checked ~ .control__indicator:after {
 display: block;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox {
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.control-group .control--radio .control__indicator:after {
 left: 4px;
 top: 4px;
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: green;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox .control__indicator:after {
 left: 6px;
 top: 0;
 width: 7px;
 height: 14px;
 border: solid #fff;
 border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.control-group .control--checkbox input:checked ~ .control__indicator {
 background-color: green;
 border: 1px solid green;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox input:disabled ~ .control__indicator:after {
 border-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox input:disabled ~ .control__indicator:after {
 border-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox .control__indicator {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 top: 0;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="facet-group">
  <h3>Operating System</h3>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control control--checkbox">Apple iOS (42)
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>

    <label class="control control--checkbox">Android (20)
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>

    <label class="control control--checkbox">Windows (8)
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: This can also be done in pure CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same results by using CSS, no JS/jQ required.

### Demo

```css
fieldset {
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 0 0 0 25px
}

legend {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.chx {
  display: none
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.chx:checked+label {
  font-weight: 900
}

.chx+label b {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.chx:checked+label b {
  background: forestgreen;
}

.chx:checked+label b::before {
  display: block;
  content: '✔';
  font-family: 'Arial Black';
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>

  <legend>Operating Systems</legend>

  <input id='chx0' class='chx' type='checkbox'>
  <label for='chx0'><b></b> Apple iOS(42)</label><br>

  <input id='chx1' class='chx' type='checkbox'>
  <label for='chx1'><b></b> Android(20)</label><br>

  <input id='chx2' class='chx' type='checkbox'>
  <label for='chx2'><b></b> Windows(8)</label><br>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `this.checked` to check its value...if checked set `font-weight:bold` using **[css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** jQuery

```js
$(".control--checkbox input").on("change", function() {
  var font = this.checked === true ? "bold" : "normal";
  $(this).closest(".control--checkbox").css("font-weight", font);
})
```

```css
.control-group {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.control-group .control {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.control-group .control input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.control-group .control__indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: white;
}

.control-group .control--radio .control__indicator {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.control-group .control:hover input~.control__indicator,
.control-group .control input:focus~.control__indicator {
  background: #fff;
}

.control-group .control input:checked~.control__indicator {
  background: #fff;
}

.control-group .control__indicator:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.control-group .control input:checked~.control__indicator:after {
  display: block;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.control-group .control--radio .control__indicator:after {
  left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox .control__indicator:after {
  left: 6px;
  top: 0;
  width: 7px;
  height: 14px;
  border: solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.control-group .control--checkbox input:checked~.control__indicator {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox input:disabled~.control__indicator:after {
  border-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox input:disabled~.control__indicator:after {
  border-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox .control__indicator {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="facet-group">
  <h3>Operating System</h3>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control control--checkbox">Apple iOS (42)
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
    <label class="control control--checkbox">Android (20)
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
    <label class="control control--checkbox">Windows (8)
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Well you can achieve this by using only css if you are allowed to change some of your markup like wrapping the text inside the `.control__indicator` div and some changes on css too...

```css
.control-group {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.control-group .control {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.control-group .control input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.control-group .control__indicator:after,
.control-group .control__indicator:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox .control__indicator:after {
  left: 8px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 12px;
  border: solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.control-group .control--checkbox input:checked~.control__indicator:before {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox input:disabled~.control__indicator:after {
  border-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox input:disabled~.control__indicator:after {
  border-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox .control__indicator:before {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.control-group .control--checkbox input:checked~.control__indicator {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="facet-group">
  <h3>Operating System</h3>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control control--checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <div class="control__indicator">Apple iOS (42)</div>
    </label>
    <label class="control control--checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <div class="control__indicator">Android (20)</div>
    </label>
    <label class="control control--checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <div class="control__indicator">Windows (8)</div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```js
// This code will fire on checkbox change event.
 $('.control--checkbox input').on('change',function(){
      // Getting parent div of the current checkbox
      var $parentDiv = $(this).parent();
      // Here checking whether it is checked or not
      if(this.checked){
           // If it is checked this code will execute
           $parentDiv.css({fontWeight: "bold"})
      } else {
           // If it is not checked this code will execute
           $parentDiv.css({fontWeight: "400"})
      }
});
```

```css
.control-group {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.control-group .control {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 18px;
 padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.control-group .control input {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 opacity: 0;
}

.control-group .control__indicator {
 position: absolute;
 top: 2px;
 left: 0;
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 background: white;
}

.control-group .control--radio .control__indicator {
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.control-group .control:hover input ~ .control__indicator,
  .control-group .control input:focus ~ .control__indicator {
 background: #fff;
}

.control-group .control input:checked ~ .control__indicator {
 background: #fff;
}

.control-group .control__indicator:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
}

.control-group .control input:checked ~ .control__indicator:after {
 display: block;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox {
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.control-group .control--radio .control__indicator:after {
 left: 4px;
 top: 4px;
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: green;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox .control__indicator:after {
 left: 6px;
 top: 0;
 width: 7px;
 height: 14px;
 border: solid #fff;
 border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.control-group .control--checkbox input:checked ~ .control__indicator {
 background-color: green;
 border: 1px solid green;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox input:disabled ~ .control__indicator:after {
 border-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox input:disabled ~ .control__indicator:after {
 border-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.control-group .control--checkbox .control__indicator {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 top: 0;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="facet-group">
  <h3>Operating System</h3>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control control--checkbox">Apple iOS (42)
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>

    <label class="control control--checkbox">Android (20)
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>

    <label class="control control--checkbox">Windows (8)
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```